# How to CSS a vertical line at 100% of the container

Tags: css, height, line

I have a vertical line centrally positioned on my page. But I want the line to be the full with of the container the vertical line div is sitting in. When I use height: 100%; on the vertical line div the line only gets to the size of the height of my monitor resolution. This is the CSS for the line:

```
.line {        
border-left: 6px solid  #3C948B;
margin-left: -3px;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;        
z-index:-5;}
```

Comment: please show us a fiddle with the actual (minimal) markup and the complete css

Comment: add position:relative to parent element

Answer (score -1):

When you are using percentage heights, you have to check the parent height as well. And then the height of the parent's parent, etc. This probably means you need to add a `height: 100%` to your `html, body` tags. And potentially to any wrappers you have below them.

Comment: the element is set with position:absolute